# Did the documentary parts of The Mysterious Cities of Gold air in the UK, Japan and US?

Tags: animation, mysterious-cities-of-gold

At the end of each original French episode of The Mysterious Cities of Gold there is a little documentary about the real locations and people featured in the show.

Some of the segments feature Mayan people wearing little more than loincloths, particularly the women. They are also referred to as "Indians" which is a somewhat outdated term now. The DVD release in the UK is rated PG, probably as a result of this.

My memory of the 80s is hazy. Were these segments broadcast in the UK on the BBC? And what about the broadcasts in Japan on NHK and in the United States?

Comment: My memory of the 80s is also hazy, but it includes Cities of Gold, and it includes absolutely no such documentary epilogues. End anecdote. When you say 'little', how long are we talking? It may be possible to surmise from historical TV listings whether there was time for them to be included.

Comment: @AakashM they are maybe 1-2 minutes and play just before the end credits.

Comment: I can’t remember from the (two?) broadcasts on CBBC in the 80s either. They were in the versions available on Amazon Prime a couple of years ago, but presumably they were from the DVD.

Comment: They were broadcast on RTE (Ireland) anyway, so there were certainly English language versions of them, though admittedly that doesn't really answer your question

Answer (score 3):

According to this documentary:

The US airing of the show on Nickelodeon cut the documentary portions for time reasons so that it would be able to fit more ad breaks whilst airing the show.

Comment: Thanks, although "time reasons" sounds like an excuse given the content and sensitivities of US television.

Comment: @user - although given the US love of ad breaks I would be willing to believe it...

Answer (score 1):

The documentary section was broadcast in Australia. I watched the series as a child (approximately 30 years ago), and even though I couldn't remember any of the episodes, I could remember the theme tune of the main part of the show, and the introduction to the documentary section.

The 2012 series, which is broadcast by [National Indigenous Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Indigenous_Television), which is part of the [Special Broadcasting Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Broadcasting_Service), also includes the documentary section.